# Using HTML.Encode on a Select List in ASP.NET MVC 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, encoding

In my ASP.NET MVC application I am using a select list control to generate a list for a multiselect widget:

```
<%=Html.ListBoxFor( m => m.Product.Name, 
           new SelectList( 
               Model.Products.Where( 
               s => !Model.Product.Any( 
                   t => t.Id == s.Id.Value 
                   ) ).OrderBy( t => t.Name ), "Id", "Name", 
                   new { multiselect = "multiselect", @class = "fancySelect products"}     ) ) %>
```

Which will generate a list of items. The problem is that some of them need encoding:

```
 <span>C&#333;netic&trade; Technology</span>
```

If I render this item directly to the UI using a simple response.write I see this:

```
<p class="c">Cōnetic&trade; Technology</p>
```

How would I go about integrating an Html.Encode into my select list statement to produce the same encoding result? Or is there a better encoding method that will effect select lists on a global level?

This is MVC 2 btw, so no razor.

Comment: MVC is a architectural pattern, ASP.NET MVC 2 is a framework. Do not confuse them. It's like referring to IE as "the internet".

Comment: I'm not familiar with this "the internet" thing you speak of... I'll have to get a book on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode data before displaying, and it should render as expected.
Here you example which we used in our asp.net mvc2 project:

```
<%= Html.Encode(ViewData["PasswordLength"]) %>
```

It is in a namespace System.Web.Mvc, and it converts the specified string to an HTML-encoded string.

Comment: I would prefer not to put the select list into view data; we don't use view data at all in our application, so it would not pass code review. I appreciate the suggestion though. I'm hoping there is an expression that will help me, or a best practice.

Comment: Did you try to encode your data in a service call? In this way you would be able to map your clean(already encoded) data to the ViewModel.

Comment: The problem with that approach is the data is encoded correctly for the list, but not the drop down (see the <p> tag? It is encoded right below the ddl) so I can not justify that change in the model :/